# How to print out a 10 x 10 grid of objects to console

Tags: objective-c

I am making a battleships game to play in console - How do you NSLog strings so they appear as a 10 x 10 grid and not a long list. Each coordinate is @"X" object from the boardArray.
Ideally I would like to do it in a loop - but, whatever !
Thank you.

```
NSMutableArray *boardArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:110];
NSMutableString *blank =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"X"];

for (int x = 0; x < 101; x++) {
    [boardArray insertObject:blank atIndex:x];
}


for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++){

    // what goes here to print (NSLog) a 10 x 10 grid of objects
    // each object is a string @"X" from the boardArray.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick Example:

```
// Create Array (01, 02, 03, 04, 05, etc.)

NSMutableArray *theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [theArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",i]];
}

// Print Array

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSArray *subArray = [theArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0+(i*10),10)];
    NSLog(@"%@",[subArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
}
```

Output:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to me to make your model match your structure e.g. 10 x 10 is 2 dimensional therefore use a 2D structure.

```
  NSMutableArray *board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
  NSMutableArray *row   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [row addObject:@"X"];
  }

  [board addObject:row];

  NSMutableArray *preFilledRow = nil;

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    preFilledRow = [row mutableCopy];
    [board addObject:preFilledRow];
    [preFilledRow release]; preFilledRow = nil;
  }

  [row release]; row = nil;

  for (NSMutableArray *boardRow in board) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [boardRow componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
  // printf("%s\n", [[boardRow componentsJoinedByString:@" "] UTF8String]); <- Use this if you don't want additional info printed
  }

  [board release]; board = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the NSMutableString class to construct your string to then display in your NSLog()

Answer (score 0):

You could use C's `printf()` which works just like NSLog, but doesn't print the actual log info (the time and other info), and doesn't automatically put a new line (you still can using `\n`)

Comment: Thanks everybody for all your answers - They all work well but the best one for me was Annes.